# Computer hangs while using Ubuntu but not during Windows

Tags: 16.04

I have a dual boot computer with ubuntu and windows 8. whenever I use windows it works absolutely fine but it hangs too much when I use Ubuntu.It almost hangs after every hour.

Comment: Do you have SWAP partition setup ? How old is your installation ? Do you clear cache ? You can use tools like system load indicator to see what's causing the lag.

Comment: yes, I have SWAP partition setup. I installed 16.04 about a year ago but the problem starts about 2 months ago. I'll try system load indicator.Thanks

Comment: Removing cache worked little but it still hangs and I tried system load indicator still not sure about the reason.

Comment: Stacer might be more helpful here. See which process is taking resources. You can even optimize PC using Stacer https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer

Comment: I tried Stacer. whenever I open more than 2 software or in a single browser more than 6-7 tabs, the memory usage goes to 3gib and laptop starts hanging.